# Using memcpy(...) to read Value(s) at a Physical Address

Tags: c, memcpy

I need to read a value in an address at 0x2428 (flash memory of a MCU). How do I use memcpy to read the value?

```
 uint8_t *newData ,x;
 memcpy( newData, 0x2428, sizeof x);
```

But, I get

> Error[Pe167]: argument of type "int" is incompatible with parameter of
>   type "void const *

How should I fix the error?

Comment: cast the address to `const void *` perhaps?

Comment: Why even use `memcpy()`, when you can simply initialize and dereference a pointer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to pass a memory address (0x2428) as the destination address of the memcpy operation, but the compiler simply sees it as a const int value (integer literal) when it is expecting a const void *.  You will have to at the very least cast it to a data type of (const void *) 0x2428 to have a chance for this syntax to work.

Comment: Its worth noting that this is really really bad practice - trying to directly access specific memory is an activity that happens quite often on PICs and other low-power embedded devices, but it is very error-prone and can bite you quite badly.

Comment: Excellent, glad to hear it worked!  When you have a chance, please mark this as the solution for your question, so it is marked as "Answered" for the community.

Cheers!

Comment: This practice is not at all error-prone as long as you have a memory map and everything is where it should be. There is no risk at all. The risk would come from guessing or experimenting with hard-coded addresses.

Comment: @nicomp The practice **can be** error prone if the code mapping the specific memory map is used to support more than one iteration of a H/W platform, and there is a change in the MM from ver1.0 of a Device to ver2.0 - but you're right.  Follow the documentation, and you should have no problems :-)

It's led many an embedded programmer to spend many a long nite saying "Why doesn't this work"